# Compartilhamento de objeto JSON entre diferentes clusters

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa tarde,
Gostaria de saber como faço para compartilhar um objeto JSON entre diferentes clusters.
Atualmente tenho 3 clusters ouvindo três portas diferentes. E preciso que se tenha um objeto salvo na memória para que os três clusters possam acessar as informações deste objeto.

```
var express = require('express');
var net = require('net');
var Files = require('./lib/Files');

var app = express();
var port = 9000;

if(!myObject) {
    // Cria o objeto na memória para que os outros sockets possam acessar
}

// Cria o Servidor
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    if (config.STRLOG) {
        console.log("Dispositivo Conectado: " + socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort);
    }

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('> SOCKET ERROR');
        Files.SocketErrorLog(port, err);
        console.log('------------------');
    });
}).listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Esse ficheiro é estático? ou deve ser acedido e/ou modificado por servidores diferentes? Existe alguma base de dados?

Comment: A ideia é que quando instanciado o objeto, as informações sejam buscadas no banco. Após instanciado ele é colocado na memória para que os outros sockets possam acessá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o banco de dados REDIS para salvar seu json e seus clusters podem acessar os objetos de lá ex:

```
var express = require('express'),
redis = require('redis'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
session = require('express-session'),
redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
logger = require('morgan'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var client = redis.createClient(),//CREATE REDIS CLIENT
    app = express();

app.use(cookieParser('strongsecretcode'));
app.use(session(
    {
        secret: 'strongsecretcodehere', 
        store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client }),
        saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored,
        resave: false // don't save session if unmodified
    }
));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/yoursession/set/:value', function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.params.value;
    res.send('session saved in Redis');
});

app.get('/yoursession/get/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.user)
        res.send(req.session.user);
    else
        res.send("no session value stored in Redis ");
});

app.use('/', router);
var server = app.listen(2001, function() {
    console.log('REDIS SESSION server is listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

No livro: [Aplicações web real-time com Node.js](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Wm-CCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29-IA4&lpg=PA29-IA4&dq=sessoes%20com%20redis&source=bl&ots=_ctY-lAsbP&sig=8uOB3fADbw2rVpk2JGm85fKtkkM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5z4_g9-fQAhXBCpAKHe7mD-cQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=session%20redis&f=false) Página 29 explica como utilizar o redis em aplicações baseadas em clusters.

Comment: A tua resposta é bem-vinda mas é importante traduzir as partes comentadas, indicar a fonte de onde copiaste esse código e dar uma explicação do código com conteúdo teu. Assim a resposta ficaria muito melhor :) Diz-me quando tiveres feito isso que dou `+1` com gosto!

Comment: Interessante! A velocidade de acesso a este banco de dados é o mesmo para o acesso de objetos direto na memória?

Comment: “O Redis guarda e busca, em sua base de dados, elementos chave-valor, de maneira extremamente rápida, pois mantém os dados em grande parte do tempo na memória, fazendo em curtos períodos a sincronização dos dados com disco rígido. Ele é considerado um NoSQL do chave-valor”

Trecho de: Caio Ribeiro Pereira. “Aplicações web real-time com Node.js.”